# Эффект сворачивания блока в место клика мыши

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите jquery плагин или может кому встречался скрипт реализовывающий эффект сворачивания блока в место клика мыши... Более понятнее на рисунке
[image]

Гугл при разной сопоставке вопроса к сожалению ничего не говорит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сорри, но

> эффект сворачивания блока в место
> клика мыши

**В место** или **вместо**

При наведении на блок где написано "click" его нужно свернуть?

Я наверное как гугл думаю :)

**PS [[@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan)](/users/3526/palmervan) тебя не взломали случаем, 3-4 твоих последних вопроса заставляют задумать что это не ты их задаешь, чес слово.**

**//upd**

[AeroPlugin](http://habrahabr.ru/post/95337/) в этом направлении поищи :)

Comment: в место) пример как в винде на стартовой панели сворачиваются разворачиваются активные окна) к ЗЫ скажу что в отпуск нужно, мозг не варит)

Comment: Да отпуск это полезная вещь, обновил ответ.

Comment: то что нужно! благодарен!

Comment: пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

[Попробуйте такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/23rr3/), хотя тоже не уверен, что вопрос правильно понял.

P.S. А что такое "отпуск"? ))) Забыл просто...

Comment: @Deonis я тут недавно сходил в него, не поверишь, ничего интересного, рядом компа нет, интернета нет, людей куча, воды море, лампочка огромная висит на головой, а вечером пьянки :)